# sql query not functioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewProduct]
    @ProductCode VARCHAR(200) ,
    @OMCode VARCHAR(200) ,
    @ProductName VARCHAR(200) ,
    @Category VARCHAR(200) ,
    @Balance INT ,
    @ReOrder INT ,
    @Unit VARCHAR(20) ,
    @location VARCHAR(500) ,
    @expiry DATE
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @existingProduct INT

    SET @existingProduct = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                             FROM   dbo.Products
                             WHERE  OMCode = @OMCode
                           )

    IF @existingProduct > 0 
        BEGIN

            RAISERROR(' Already Exists--',11,1)

        END

    IF @existingProduct <= 0 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO dbo.Products
            VALUES  ( @ProductCode, @OMCode, @ProductName, @Category, @Balance,
                      @ReOrder, @Unit, @location, @expiry )

        END 


GO
```

The issue now is a product with an existing OMCODE still gets inserted.
Can't seem to figure why....and i don't want to put a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the OMCode Column.

Comment: This will not solve your issue, but I would suggest using `ELSE` rather than the line `IF @existingProduct <= 0` for clarity.

Comment: Are you sure of the spelling of @OMCode? Maybe a trailing space?

Comment: What do OMCodes look like?   They are varchar(200), so there is a good chance of them not matching (extra spaces, etc.)   I would trim the value on the lookup variable.   Could possibly be casing, depending on the collation of the database, but generally SQL is case-insensitive. (MS-SQL I assume)

Comment: @Jeffery Khan i actually used ELSE before i changed the code,but it did change nothing.

Comment: @Sparky yes its MS_SQL and the OMCODE is trimmed @ the front end before calling the sproc,the collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' is also the default.

Comment: if you are using SQL server management studio, did you try to run in debug and check value of @existingProduct?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be related to concurrency? I see you're not doing any sort of locking in your SP. If the SP is executed twice "simultaneously", both executions could enter the same IF existingProduct <= 0, did you try locking ?

Quick intro here, if it's of any use: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

since you're trimming the @OMCode on the input, you may want to try this:

```
SET @existingProduct = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM   dbo.Products
                         WHERE  rtrim(ltrim(OMCode)) = @OMCode
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with just one trip to the database, for example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewProduct]
    @ProductCode VARCHAR(200) ,
    @OMCode VARCHAR(200) ,
    @ProductName VARCHAR(200) ,
    @Category VARCHAR(200) ,
    @Balance INT ,
    @ReOrder INT ,
    @Unit VARCHAR(20) ,
    @location VARCHAR(500) ,
    @expiry DATE
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Output TABLE (OMCode VARCHAR(200)) 
    INSERT INTO dbo.Products
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OMCode INTO @Output
    SELECT @ProductCode, @OMCode, @ProductName, @Category, @Balance, @ReOrder, @Unit, @location, @expiry 
    FROM (SELECT @OMCode AS OMCode) Tester
    LEFT JOIN Products ON Tester.OMCode = Products.OMCode
    WHERE Products.OMCode IS NULL

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [@Output]))
    BEGIN
         RAISERROR(' Already Exists--',11,1)
    END
```

Personally I like naming explicitly all the columns in the `INSERT` clause, it reduces chances of missplacements

```
    ...
    INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductCode,  OMCode,  ProductName,  Category,  Balance,  ReOrder,  Unit,  location,  expiry)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OMCode INTO @Output
    SELECT                    @ProductCode, @OMCode, @ProductName, @Category, @Balance, @ReOrder, @Unit, @location, @expiry 
    ...
```